# lo4net debug mode logs everything but we want custom logging only

Tags: logging, log4net, log4net-configuration

This is our configuration. It logs each and every action but we don't want it to log. When we call "logger.Debug("")" then only it should log.

```html
<log4net>
    <appender name="DebugRollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
    <datePattern value="ddMMyyyy" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelMatchFilter">
      <levelToMatch value="DEBUG"/>
    </filter>
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="=-=-=-=-=-=-%newline %date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message %newline=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-==-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-==-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=%newline " />
    </layout>
    <file value="D:\AppLog\DEBUG\App.log" />
  </appender>

  <root>
    <!--
    1.OFF - nothing gets logged
    2.FATAL 
    3.ERROR
    4.WARN
    5.INFO
    6.DEBUG
    7.ALL - everything gets logged
    -->
    <level value="ALL"/>
    <appender-ref ref="DebugRollingFileAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you have another Dll that logs to log4net and you want to see only your logs.

You can make different logger than the root logger by replace the "root" section with the following section.

```
<logger name="MyLogger" additivity="False">
     <level value="ALL" />
<appender-ref ref="DebugRollingFileAppender" />
```

Then in the code you get the logger  by name:

```
ILog myLog = LogManager.GetLogger("MyLogger");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line

```
 <level value="ALL"/>
```

to this line

```
 <level value="DEBUG"/>
```

inside the root tags

SOURCE:
https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html